# is it correct architecture of ASP.NET MVC & EF app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, architecture

I have the following repository class:

```
public class Model1Repository
{
    private NEOGOV_IdeasEntities _dataContext;
    public Model1Repository()
    {
        _dataContext = new NEOGOV_IdeasEntities();
    }
    public IdeaType IdeaType(int ID)
    {
        var q = from i in _dataContext.IdeaTypes where i.ID == ID select i;
        return q.FirstOrDefault();
    }
    ... rest methods....
}
```

following controller:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private Model1Repository _repository;

    public TestController()
    {
        _repository = new Model1Repository();
    }
    public ActionResult Tagedit()
    {
        return View(_repository.GetDataFromDB1());
    }

    public ActionResult Avatar()
    {
        return View(_repository.GetDataFromDB2());
    }
}
```

is it correct architecture? Or not? As I understand, in my case _repository variable creates for each request...

Comment: Does it work? Yes. Is it good? No. You should use Dependency Injection :) Look into Dependency Injection with Ninject. It is very easy to set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd instantiate the repository in the controller action, not the constructor. If you're positive that all controller actions will require the repository, then fair enough, but since the operations on a controller relate to the operation of the UI, it's not at all unusual to have controller methods that don't require it.

But it's really a style thing at the end of the day (OK, perhaps with some minor performance overhead); if you want to do it that way, feel free!

Comment: you wrote below about _repository as singleton. It makes sense?

Comment: In your implementation, _repository is not a singleton and that's good. In order to take advantage of connection pooling, you need to release your data context quickly. The fact that your _repository will be garbage collected after the controller action will help that happen, whereas using a singleton pattern wouldn't. But creating the repository when you need it and releasing it as quickly as possible improves that efficiency further and improves scalability.

Answer (score -2):

Can't answer for the entire architecture, but there will be one and only one repository **Model1Repository** object instantiated for the TestController, not one per request (HTTP request).

Comment: why one? Debugger says, that constructor of controller calls to each request. Ctor creates new copy of Model1Repository, ctor of Model1Repository creates new copy of NEOGOV_IdeasEntities. So, each request creates new copy of NEOGOV_IdeasEntities....

Comment: The default lifetime for a controller is per-request and since _repository is not a singleton, a new one will be created each time.